# How to reduce the height of the tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

How can i reduce the height of the tabs as given in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/gMeQH/)
How to do that?

Comment: Always put the relevant markup/code **in the question itself**. why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Never ever use a negative margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the most specific css selector for that element, which in this case would mean this, to completely remove the top and bottom padding:

```
.ui-navbar-noicons li .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner, .ui-navbar-noicons .ui-navbar-toggle .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest starting to use an inspector tool, like Chrome's developer tools, to examine which classes apply to your elements.

Answer (score 0):

The height for these tabs is determined by the padding-top and padding-bottom of the `<span class="ui-btn-inner">` element, reducing this padding will set the height you're looking for.

How you do this is up to you, you can either change the existing rule but bear in mind that this will change every tab in your site.  If it's only for that page add a different class to the span and set the height there.